# Changing the color of navigation bar

Tags: css, wordpress, navigationbar, woothemes

I am working on the Mystile theme by WooThemes. I have used custom CSS to change the color of the background, footer and side wings. But, I can't change the color of the navigation bar. 

[image: Navigation Bar]

In the screenshot, the navigation bar has some shade of `grey` but I would like to have it in `white` i.e. `#FFFFFF`. Please help me.

Comment: When you inspect the element using dev tools does that navigation bar element has any class or id set on it? If so should just be a question of overwriting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css file change:

```
#header #navigation ul.nav > li a
{
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

to

```
#header #navigation ul.nav > li a
{
    background: #fff;
}
```

and it should change the colour.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask something ?

Comment: Technically you just did...it depends on the question

Comment: Hahaha! I just wanted to know that if the id is : '#main-nav' and the class is 'nav fr parent', then how do I override it ?

Comment: You can find it in the css file and change it,